# Java MySQL Update Query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting the error "cannot issue data".

Here is the SSCCE

```
//package mysqltest;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.TextArea.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;

    public class test extends JApplet {

      public JTextArea c;

      public void init() {

          c = new JTextArea();

          add(c);
          c.append("Looking for database...");

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "mystik";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        String loggedusername = getParameter("name");
        try {
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          props.put("user", "root");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mystik", props);
          c.append("\nConnected to the database");


                        c.append("\nGetting stats for: " + loggedusername);
                        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement( "select * from `user` where `username` = '"+loggedusername+"'");
                        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
                        // just a dumb mysql statement!
                        while(result.next())
                        {
                        c.append("\nUsername: "+result.getString(2)+ "\nLevel: "+result.getString(6)+"\nEXP: "+result.getString(8)+"\n");
                        }

                        PreparedStatement updateEXP = conn.prepareStatement( "update`user` set `exp` = '666'  where `username` = '"+loggedusername+"'");
                        ResultSet updateEXP_done = updateEXP.executeQuery();

                        while(result.next())
                        {
                        c.append("\nUsername: "+result.getString(2)+ "\nLevel: "+result.getString(6)+"\nEXP: "+result.getString(8)+"\n");
                        }


          conn.close();
          c.append("\nDisconnected from database");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    }
```

and it works... and it's just that `update` java query doesn't.

Here is what the JTextArea sees:

```
Looking for database...
Connected to the database
Getting stats for: weka
Username: weka
Level: 1
EXP: 1
```

and here is my error:

```
added manifest
adding: test.class(in = 2440) (out= 1308)(deflated 46%)
adding: mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar(in = 767492) (out= 735869)(deflated
4%)

Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQu
ery().
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:436)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
2176)
        at test.init(test.java:53)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:424)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Lastly, here is how i compile using a .bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD \wamp\www\mystikrpg\mysqltest
javac -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin test.java
jar cvf mysqlTry.jar test.class mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
jarsigner -keystore dankey -storepass soccer -keypass soccer mysqlTry.jar gamerpg
appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=game.policy mysqltry.html
```

How do I fix this error? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AS [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) documentation:

> Executes the SQL statement in this
>   PreparedStatement object, which must
>   be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE
>   statement; or an SQL statement that
>   returns nothing, such as a DDL
>   statement.

To execute querys that update, delete or insert any data in your DB, you can't use `executeQuery`... You must use: `.executeUpdate(query)`

So this code (**WRONG**):

```
   PreparedStatement updateEXP = conn.prepareStatement("update `user` set `exp` = '666'  where `username` = '"+loggedusername+"'");
   ResultSet updateEXP_done = updateEXP.executeQuery();
```

Must look like (**GOOD**):

### Correct usage

```
   PreparedStatement updateEXP = conn.prepareStatement("update `user` set `exp` = ? ");
   updateEXP.setString(1, loggedusername);
   ResultSet updateEXP_done = updateEXP.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I got it. Now my when I call the second result whiel loop... it will be invisible and go directly to "Disconnected from database." Can you only use Prepared statements once?

Comment: The `next()` method of `ResultSet` moves forward to the next row, after the first `while` is end, the `ResultSet` is at the end. If you want to go around (again) in the `ResultSet`, call `result.first()`

Answer (score 6):

Also consider using a parameter for the username:

`PreparedStatement updateEXP = conn.prepareStatement("update`user`set`exp`= '666'  where`username`= ? ");`

`updateEXP.setString(1, loggedusername);`

`ResultSet updateEXP_done = updateEXP.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 4):

As per the Javadoc, DML queries (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) needs to be executed using [`executeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29), not [`executeQuery()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29). It returns an `int` with amount of affected rows.

```
PreparedStatement updateEXP = conn.prepareStatement( "update`user` set `exp` = '666'  where `username` = '"+loggedusername+"'");
int affectedRows = updateEXP.executeUpdate();
```

That said, closing the `conn` (and `Statement` and `ResultSet`!) should be done in the `finally` block, else it will still be open when an exception is been thrown before `close()` is called. Also your use of `PreparedStatement` is wrong. You're still inlining the column values by simple string concatenation instead of setting them as parameterized values. You're not taking benefit of its SQL injection prevention capabilities.

#### See also:

- [Basic JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)
- [Using PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

`executeUpdate(query)` instead of `executeQuery()`